# Eclipse is not opening in linux environment

Tags: java, eclipse

Am getting below error , when trying to open eclipse oxygen , in Red Hat Linux env 64 bit. installed jdk 8 also in the linux env.

JVM terminated. Exit code=1

/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_67-cloudera/bin/java

-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8

-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace

-XX:+UseG1GC

-XX:+UseStringDeduplication

-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8

-Xms256m

-Xmx1024m

-jar /home/cloudera/Downloads/eclipse//plugins

/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar

-os linux

-ws gtk

-arch x86_64

-showsplash /home/cloudera/Downloads/eclipse//plugins

/org.eclipse.epp.package.common_4.7.3.20180405-1200/splash.bmp

-launcher /home/cloudera/Downloads/eclipse/eclipse

-name Eclipse

--launcher.library /home/cloudera/Downloads/eclipse//plugins

/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.551.v20171108-1834

/eclipse_1630.so

-startup /home/cloudera/Downloads/eclipse//plugins

/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar

--launcher.appendVmargs

-exitdata 100015

-product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

-vm /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_67-cloudera/bin/java

-vmargs

-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8

-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace

-XX:+UseG1GC

-XX:+UseStringDeduplication

-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8

-Xms256m

-Xmx1024m

-jar /home/cloudera/Downloads/eclipse//plugins

/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar

Comment: Eclipse 4.7.3 requires Java 8 or higher, with Java 7 it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like eclipse is configured to use the wrong java version. Required is 1.8. But uses 1.7

Comment: Hi Anitha, thanks for the reply, i have installed java 1.8 as well in linux. But then also eclipse is not opening.

Comment: Hi Anitha, eclipse opened. Done changes in the eclipse.ini file for java path. so now its working. Thanks for you help

Comment: Welcome!  Accept this as answer

Comment: I reffered this link to edit the eclipse.ini file https://www.rascal-mpl.org/start/editini.html